# gui theme names

Tags: themes, gui

Please give me some names of nice GUI for linux.

I tried to install  `KDE` , but I don't like it ... And I can't find on internet the terminal commands for others.

PS: Please tell me the  `GUI` name and the terminal command (example: `$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` ).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try gnome 3 but be careful ypu can mess up your system. But I recomment to ask such things here. http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `apt-cache search -- '-desktop$'`. You should see something like:

```
[12:18 PM] ~ $ apt-cache search -- '-desktop$'
lsb-desktop - Linux Standard Base 4.0 Desktop support package
ubuntu-desktop - The Ubuntu desktop system
mythbuntu-desktop - The Mythbuntu standalone system
djvulibre-desktop - Desktop support for the DjVu image format
edubuntu-desktop - educational desktop for Ubuntu
gambas3-gb-desktop - Gambas Portland project compatibility component
gosa-desktop - Desktop integration for GOsa²
kde-plasma-desktop - KDE Plasma Desktop and minimal set of applications
kubuntu-desktop - Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
lubuntu-desktop - Lubuntu Desktop environment
matchbox-desktop - desktop application launcher for resource-limited systems
openerp-desktop - OpenERP Enterprise Resource Management - metapackage
plasma-desktop - KDE Plasma workspace for desktop and laptop computers
ubuntu-gnome-desktop - The Ubuntu GNOME Remix desktop system
ubuntustudio-desktop - Ubuntu Studio Desktop Package
xubuntu-desktop - Xubuntu desktop system
[12:18 PM] ~ $
```